# interromper e questionar

Tags: palavra-para-ideia

Estou procurando uma palavra que descreva a ação de interromper alguém e começar a fazer perguntas.

Por exemplo:

1. Um aluno está resolvendo um exercício e o professor o interrompe e começa questioná-lo.
2. Uma pessoa está caminhando e alguém pede para ela parar e pergunta "O que você está fazendo aqui?"

Posso usar o verbo **interpelar**?

Comment: Priberam diz: interpelar : interromper a quem fala. Já procurou lá?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode sim, mas o verbo em si não significa "interromper alguém e começar a fazer perguntas". *Interpelar* significa "demandar explicações de forma brusca ou exigente". Por exemplo:

> Um aluno está resolvendo um exercício e o professor começa a interpelá-lo.
>
> *Um aluno está resolvendo um exercício (portanto, ocupado) e o professor começa a demandar dele explicações (que exigem que ele interrompa o que está fazendo)*.

---

> Uma pessoa está caminhando e alguém começa a interpelá-la: "o que você está fazendo aqui?".
>
> *Uma pessoa está caminhando e alguém a interrompe bruscamente e exige que ela se explique: "o que você está fazendo aqui?"*.

Porém, *interpelar* não funcionaria neste contexto aqui:

> O jovem acariciou-lhe os cabelos e perguntou a ela se estava com saudades.

Apesar da moça ter sido interrompida e questionada, a condução do processo não foi brusca ou exigente, então ela não teria sido *interpelada*.

Comment: Fiquei em dúvida se deveria adicionar uma resposta, porque nos dicionários [Priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/interpelar) e [Dicio](https://www.dicio.com.br/interpelar/), *interromper* é um dos significados/sinônimos de *interpelar*. Gostaria que alguém comentasse a respeito.